# Having problems with Akka 2.1.2 Scheduler ('system' not recognized)

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to get a very simple recurring function loop running, according to these samples:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/scheduler.html

The code:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main extends Application {
  val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")    // this was missing!
  import system.dispatcher

  system.scheduler.schedule( 0 milliseconds, (10*1000) milliseconds, {
    println( "click!" )
  })
}
```

I get (sbt):

```
> .../src/Main.scala:34: not found: value system [error]       import
> system.dispatcher [error]              ^ [error]
> .../src/Main.scala:36: not found: value system [error]      
> system.scheduler.schedule( 0 milliseconds /*initial delay*/,
> (entry.secs*1000) milliseconds /*delay between*/, { [error]       ^
```

Where is the `system` supposed to be coming from?

**Addendum:**

I'm having the code within a 'main()' function, and I haven't inherited anything from `Actor` or `ActorSystem`. The point is I'd like to schedule functions but no go into actors with this. Is the framework thinking I must derive from something (if so, it kind-of should say it?).

Comment: An `ActorSystem` is nothing to inherit from, but it is the runtime for actors and amongst other things, the scheduler.

Comment: Is there any practical differences with "import context.dispatcher" since the actor has this context already?

Comment: @Daniel. Probably not - you are right. This whole question seems stupid now that I'm more into Akka. I think Futures would be the way to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It looks like missing of following expression before `import system.dispatcher`:

```
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
```

Comment: Yes, the confusion comes from that "import system.dispatcher" looks like a package import, but it just makes the dispatcher field of system available in scope.

Comment: That does it, thanks. Isn't it sad that one needs to search *hours* for this kind of information. The Akka doc page really misses that line! Thanks all the more! :)