# Schedule in Akka - not found

Tags: scala, akka

Here is a basic example of using schedule in Akka:

```
import akka.pattern
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.Await
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.duration

object Application extends App {
  val supervisor = ActorSystem().actorOf(Props[Supervisor])
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
  import system.dispatcher

  supervisor.scheduler.scheduleOnce(120 seconds) {
    val future = supervisor ? Supervisor.Start
    val resultIdList = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[List[MyIdList]]
    supervisor ! resultIdList
  }
}
```

I'm really confused of Akka's documentation. Here [Having problems with Akka 2.1.2 Scheduler ('system' not recognized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684901/having-problems-with-akka-2-1-2-scheduler-system-not-recognized) was said that `import system.dispatcher` is not a package import but something else. What is that then?

What is `system`? Do I have to replace it with `supervisor`? Even if I didn't do that and keep using `system`, I'd have pretty much the same errors:

```
//(using system)
value scheduler is not a member of akka.actor.ActorRef
not found: value system

//or (using supervisor)

not found: value system
not found: value system
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
val system = ActorSystem()
val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props[Supervisor])
```

Comment: that's fine. why can't I move `import system.dispatcher` to all other import statements? I causes en error, but why?

Comment: Because `system` is just not in scope there. It is just a name you give to your `ActorSystem`.

Comment: why do I have to import it, can I use a full name instead of importing and how? And what's the name of this procedure, I've never seen something like this before.

Comment: You are using futures. Futures need some sort of thread pool to run their call backs on. A dispatcher is an abstraction over an execution context, which is an abstraction over a thread pool. Now instead of passing the execution context along every time you register a call back on a future you can make sure that it is just in the implicit scope so the compiler can insert it for you.

Comment: I'm not asking about technical details, I'm asking about syntaxis only.

Answer (score 1):

(Posting as answer since does not fit as comment)

Marius, you were referring to another question which started with this line:

```
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
```

That is the identifier 'system' the import statement is referring to.
The line

```
import system.dispatcher
```

means that the dispatcher member of the variable system will be available in scope (you can use the name 'dispatcher' to refer to 'system.dispatcher' from that point). This also means that *since dispatcher is an implicit* that it will be now available for implicit resolution. Please note that the signature of schedule is

```
scheduleOnce(delay: FiniteDuration, runnable: Runnable)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Cancellable
```

So it either needs an explicitly passed ExecutionContext, or an implicit one. By using the import statement you bring the dispatcher (which is an ExecutionContext) into scope, so you don't have to provide it manually.

Comment: can I avoid doing `import system.dispatcher` by using a full name and how?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? Anyway, you can do it like

    system.scheduleOnce(yourDelay)(yourTask)(system.dispatcher)

The only difference from your code is now that the 3rd parameter is passed explicitly and not resolved implicitly. You still need to have your ActorSystem inside a variable (in my example 'system') though. (Inside actors it is available through 'context.system')

Comment: I have seen the code like that before, I only have used import to import packages.

Comment: `case class Dog(name: String)`;`val dog = Dog("Snoopy")`; `import dog._`; `println(name)` instead of `println(dog.name)`.